# Index values from cell by comparing with another cell

Tags: matlab, indexing, concatenation

I have 2 cells, **B** and **M**. **B** is nx1 cell and **M** is a nx2 cell. Some of the values in **B** are blanks. The rest is the same as **M{:,2}**. Something like this:

```
B=
'beta001.img'  
'beta002.img'  
[]  
[]  
[]  
'beta006.img'
[]  
...
```

And

```
M=
67    'beta001.img'  
89    'beta002.img'  
34    'beta003.img'  
14    'beta004.img' 
15    'beta005.img' 
32    'beta006.img'  
...
```

I would like to create a cell **C** that contains values from the 1st column of M but only if the corresponding values in second column match those in B. Basically, with the example above, **C** should be:

```
67
89
32
```

I can see there are at least two options. The easiest would be doing a horzcat of B and M then get rid of all the rows that contain a blank. I tried:

```
C=horzcat(B,M);
C=R(~cellfun('isempty',C));
```

Unfortunately that didn't work. Since I want to learn how to use ismember, the second option is to use that to compare across B and M. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your approach corrected:

This concatenates the matrices. Then extracts the rows, where there aren't any empty entries and then the second column of the result.

```
C = horzcat(B,M);
C = C(~any(cellfun('isempty',C),2),:);
C = cell2mat(C(:,2));
```

But you don't need to concatenate the cell-arrays to achieve what you are doing.

### Simplified approach:

You can just find the lines where B is not empty, and then take the first column of `M` of said corresponding lines.

```
isBnotEmpty = ~cellfun(@isempty, B);
C = cell2mat(M(isBnotEmpty,1));
```

Comment: Thank you, knedlsepp. This yields the opposite result though. Only the non-matching values are retained.